# Windows Phone 8 GPS precise coordinates C# Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, gps, tracking

Hope I'm asking in the right place and the right way :)
If anyone has links or directions, would be appreciated also.

Shortly, I have a Windows Phone 8 application in Silverlight. Using Silverlight.
What I want to accomplish:
- GPS tracking
- Precise location
- Draw line between locations- tracking
- Work in background (Even when phone locked or app at background)

I have code right now:

```
    hasGPS = true; //GPS working
    isTracking = true; //Tracks movement

    userPushpin.Template = (ControlTemplate)(this.Resources["PushpinControlTemplate1"]);
    App.Geolocator = new Geolocator();

    App.Geolocator.MovementThreshold = 1; //Doesn't seem to affect intervals

    App.Geolocator.PositionChanged +=
       new TypedEventHandler<Geolocator,
          PositionChangedEventArgs>(geo_PositionChanged);

    Geoposition pos = await App.Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

    geoLat = pos.Coordinate.Latitude; //Latitude
    geoLong = pos.Coordinate.Longitude; //Longitude

    map1.SetView(new GeoCoordinate(geoLat, geoLong, 7), 15); //Set where the app is looking

    userPushpin.Template = (ControlTemplate)(this.Resources["PushpinControlTemplate2"]);

    userPushpin.Location = new GeoCoordinate(geoLat, geoLong);//SharedInformation.myLatitude, SharedInformation.myLongitude);

    map1.Children.Add(userPushpin);
```

Bit weird code, I know. The connection part is not in this block, can share that also.
Main issue is that GPS tracks me, but not as tight intervals. Also, sometimes the GPS jumps, making line drawing a bit weird (Jumps few meters quickli away and back, making a spike).
The program needs to also run in the background, that's why Silverlight is working.

Also I have to think for future, how to save all previous locations or track.

Any info is welcome!
If Clarification needed, please do not hesitate to ask!
Thank You upfront!

Comment: tried using `Geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters` ??

Comment: Hi. It's a good notice. I tried it, but for some reason still didn't work. The distance it marks my distance and location still varies. Nothing much changed, to sum it up.

Comment: I guess that's it from my side then. But would like to point to a link that may be useful. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-24-Getting-Started-with-the-AroundMe-Project

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a problem in the Geolocator Accuracy, try changing it to High with something like this:

```
private Geolocator App = new Geolocator(GeolocatorAccuracy.High);
```